# Plotting multiple binhex with the same z levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have meteorological records for a point, these include temperature and solar irradiation. I want to plot them against another variable, that we shall call Rating, and see how the data are distributed. This is what I'm doing:

```
d1 <- ggplot(data = mydata, aes(Temperature, Rating, fill = ..density..)) + stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE) + opts(aspect.ratio = 1)#, legend.position = "none") 
d2 <- ggplot(data = mydata, aes(Solar.Irrad, Rating, fill = ..density..)) + stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE) + opts(aspect.ratio = 1)#, legend.position = "none")
```

I get both things on the same window by using grid.arrange from package gridExtra:

```
grid.arrange(d1,d2, nrow=1)
```

[image: Two graphs together, different z scale]
This produces the image shown. Now, my problem is that I would really like that both graphs shared their z scale: the legend should be the same and the color scheme should be homogeneous through different graphs. Is this possible? I'm totally lost here, do anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: you will get infinitely better answers if you provide a reproducible example, i.e. `dput(mydata)` into the question.

Comment: You can specify the limits of the fill scale: `scale_fill_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.05))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you thought about using the faceting capabilities within ggplot2 directly? You can allow for free scales as a parameter in the call to `facet_wrap()`. Here's an example for you:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)
#Sample data.frame.
dat <- data.frame(
  rating = sample(500:2500, 1000, TRUE)
  , Solar.Radiation = sample(0:1200, 1000, TRUE)
  , Ambient.Temperature = sample(-10:25, 1000, TRUE)
  )

#Melt data.frame for plotting
dat.m <- melt(dat, id.vars = "rating")

#Plotting
ggplot(dat.m, aes(value, rating, fill = ..density..)) +
  stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE) +  opts(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  facet_wrap(facets = ~  variable, scales = "free_x")
```

Comment: I was about to suggest to choose a convenient common No. bins to pass to `stat_binhex()` (`bins` or `binwidth`), but facetting is definitively the way to go, so my +1!

Comment: @chl - thanks. I really take advantage of the `scales` argument in the facets frequently to display information that is consistent across one axis. For example when reviewing diagnostic plots from CBC HB models, I find it helpful to check convergence by reviewing the percent certainty, RLH, average variance, and parameter RMS values. All of these have different scales on the y-axis, but should converge and flatten out if you include enough iterations in your model run ( x-axis). It's pretty trivial to set up an R script to parse the log files from HB and generate these plots as a pdf or jpeg